# error in lip detection algorithm of my matlab code

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-compiler

I am getting error in my Matlab code. I am using R2009b version

> Frame index must be a numeric value greater than zero and less
>   than or equal to the number of frames in the file.
>
> Error in ==> mmreader.read at 74
>           videoFrames = read(getImpl(obj), index);
>
> Error in ==> testing at 10
>   Ii=read(mov,k*10);

Comment: How are we suppose to help, if you don't provide sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but I'm guessing that your frame index is not:

> a numeric value greater than zero and less than or equal to the number
>   of frames in the file.

MATLAB is telling you that the error is happening in `mmreader.read`, and it is happening when you call `mmreader.read` at this point in your file `testing`:

```
Ii=read(mov,k*10);
```

If your movie reader object `mov` contains less than `k*10` frames, or if `k` is zero or a negative number, you are asking MATLAB to do something impossible.

These sort of errors can be easily tracked down by typing `dbstop if error` at the command line, which means that when there is an error you enter debug mode.  At this point you can then check what the value of `k` is, and also the number of available frames in `mov`.